# update mysql row when more than a week

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to update mySql row with a number which is represents a status. For example :

```
1 = New
2 = Old
```

By default, when a new data has been added to mySql. The status is set to "1" automatically. And this is the point. I'd like to update it automatically to "2" when the day is more than a week (7 days). Here is the codes:

```
<?php
$_toDay=date("Y-m-d");
.....
while($rec_gid=mysql_fetch_array($result_gid)){
$gid=$rec_gid['goods_id'];
$dateDB=$rec_gid['goods_date'];

$_diff = abs(strtotime($_toDay) - strtotime($dateDB));
$_years = floor($_diff / (365*60*60*24));
$_mon = floor(($_diff - $_years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$_days = floor(($_diff - $_years * 365*60*60*24 - $_mon*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

if($_days>7){//if older than a week then change status
$sql_updStts="update goods_db set stts='2' where id='$_gid'";
$result_updStts=mysql_db_query($dbname,$sql_updStts);
}//close while
?>
```

I've tried this script but the outcome is not as I expected. Even the $_days is more than a week. mySql is not update. I don't know why. Any idea?

Comment: you could run a php script using cronjob which would check for the database entries and if matched then would the update running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 UPDATE goods_db SET stts = '2' 
 WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),goods_date) >= 7 
 AND stts='1'
```

Comment: This one sounds good, I'll try and let you know the result. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** or **[MYSQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** to avoid SQL Injection

Example of using PDO extension:

```
<?php

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $name);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $value);

    // insert one row
    $name = 'one';
    $value = 1;
    $stmt->execute();

?>
```

So in your case

```
<?php

    $query = "UPDATE Goods_DB 
              SET stts = ? 
              WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),goods_date) > 6 AND stts = ?"

    $valueA = 2;
    $valueB = 1;

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $valueA);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $valueB);


    $stmt->execute();

?>
```

make it a habit of using PDO or MySQLi Extension.

Another thing of doing this is by creating an `EVENT SCHEDULER` on the server.In this case, the server will automatically update the `goods_db` everyday.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    EVENT `archive_blogs`
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
    DO BEGIN
                  UPDATE Goods_DB 
                  SET stts = 2 
                  WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),goods_date) > 6 AND stts = 1;
    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

**[More on this link (How to Create Scheduled Events in MySQL).](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/)**

Comment: This one seems way too professional and I don't know any line of yours - Too hard for me. Well I'll try and let you know the result anyway. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to save `$_gid` or `$gid`?
try this one

```
$sql_updStts=sprintf("update goods_db set stts='2' where id='%s'",$_gid)
```